# mongodb lookup aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

I have an issue while running this query in mongodb.

```
db.user.aggregate([
      {
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'role',
       localField: 'Role_id',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'role'
     }
},
{
 $lookup:
     {
       from: 'location',
       localField: 'Location_id',
       foreignField: '_id',
       as: 'location'
     }   
 }
])
```

The collections are as follows

//Location collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b9b9b95565ef59ac1bcc99"),
    "locationcode" : "L001",
    "locationname" : "Pune"
}
```

//Role collection

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b9b8ef5565ef59ac1bcc49"),
    "rolename" : "SuperAdmin"
}
```

//User collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b9bad55565ef59ac1bcd04"),
    "LoginId" : "Sylvester_M001",
    "Password" : "123456",
    "Name" : "Sylvester",
    "EmployeeId" : "M001",
    "Role_id" : ObjectId("58b9b8ef5565ef59ac1bcc49"),
    "Location_id" : ObjectId("58b9b9b95565ef59ac1bcc99")
}
```

when I run the aggregate lookup to join the three collections I get

//Resulting collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58b9bad55565ef59ac1bcd04"),
    "LoginId" : "Sylvester_M001",
    "Password" : "123456",
    "Name" : "Sylvester",
    "EmployeeId" : "M001",
    "Role_id" : ObjectId("58b9b8ef5565ef59ac1bcc49"),
    "Location_id" : ObjectId("58b9b9b95565ef59ac1bcc99"),
    "role" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58b9b8ef5565ef59ac1bcc49"),
            "rolename" : "SuperAdmin"
        }
    ],
    "location" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("58b9b9b95565ef59ac1bcc99"),
            "locationcode" : "L001",
            "locationname" : "Pune"
        }
    ]
}
```

but after a few seconds, it changes to

```
{
"$err":"Invalid ns[]",
"code":73
}
```

why does this happen? any clarifications as to where I am going wrong? what triggers this?

Comment: Unable to simulate your error. I used the same code you did above and got the correct response that you first got as well. I executed this from the mongo shell. Where did you execute this from?

Comment: Can You write a mongoose script to get the aggregate data?